# Why use integrals when building exponential composite functions?

Tags: predictive-models, integral, numerical-integration, decomposition, composite

I recently read [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0016706109004224), which describes a generalisation for statistical exponential decay models used in ecology. Essentially, the parameter $k$ of the exponential decay function $f(x) = ce^{-kx}$ is recognised to be dynamic relative to $x$ rather than constant and modelled by a nested function $g(x)$ rather than a parameter, so that $h(x) = ce^{-g(x)x}$. However, the authors of the paper derive $h(x)$ in a different way. They start with the differential of $f(x)$, $\frac{dC}{dx}=-kC$ or $\frac{dC}{C}=-kdx$, then substitute $k$ with $g(x)$ to get $\frac{dC}{C}=-g(x)dx$ and integrate last, yielding $h(x) = ce^{-(\int_0^xg(x)dx)}$.

**First question**: Why start with the differential of $f(x)$ and integrate only after function composition, i.e. substituting $g(x)$ into $f(x)$?

One example of $g(x)$ is another variant of the exponential decay function itself: $g(x) = a + be^{-kx}$. This example is common in ecology because whatever entity it is that decays, its more resistant parts decay last and slowest, meaning the exponential decay rate declines exponentially. Simply substituted into $f(x)$, this yields the double exponential function $h(x) = ce^{-(a+be^{-kx})x}$. However, the authors of the paper derive this specific form of $h(x)$ in a different way. They first integrate $g(x)$ relative to $x$ to get $\int_0^xg(x)dx=ax-b/k(e^{-kx}-1)$ and only then substitute this into $f(x)$, yielding $h(x) = ce^{-(ax-b/k(e^{-kx}-1))}$ instead.

**Second question**: Why integrate $g(x)$ relative to $x$ before function composition, i.e. substituting $g(x)$ into $f(x)$?

I recognise that my first and second questions are related since the authors’ choice in the first step gives rise to their choice in the second step. My first impression was that the authors' reasons were of a purely statistical nature with the goal of optimising parameter estimation, but then I plotted the two versions of $h(x)$ in `R` and they do not seem to be mathematically equivalent (note that $c$ is parsed as `c0` because `c` is a function in `R`).

```
set.seed(10)
x <- 1:250
c0 <- 2
a <- 0.01
b <- 0.07
k <- 0.01
y1 <- c0 * exp(-(a * x - b/k * (exp(-k * x) - 1))) # authors' h(x)
y2 <- c0 * exp(-(a + b * exp(-k * x)) * x) # my h(x)
dens(y1 - y2) # difference is not zero
plot(y1, y2) # plot y2 as a function of y1
abline(0, 1) # identity line
# y1 and y2 are not identical
```

Furthermore, the authors stress the need to use the integral of $g(x)$ throughout the paper and conclude

> Our approach allows to fit virtually any decomposition dataset, as long as (i) the change in the decomposition rate can be described as a mathematical equation, and (ii) this equation is integrable in the interval (0, *t*), where *t* is the total decomposition time [equivalent to *x* in the general sense]. This second condition can be a problem.

Using probabilistic languages such as Stan and other Bayesian tools, the differential of $f(x)$ can be used as the prediction function instead of its integrated form. It follows that $g(x)$ can be substituted into the differential of $f(x)$ and the resulting differential equation used directly in the model without the need to derive $h(x)$ by integration. This would consequently avoid having to integrate $g(x)$.

**Third question**: Would it be possible to expand the authors’ method to non-integrable $g(x)$ if the differential of $f(x)$ were directly used in the model?

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: An examination of almost any physical theory developed since Newton's time will reveal the utility and interpretive power of formulating laws and models in terms of differential equations.  It's unclear what your questions concerning "before inserting" are about: are you perhaps trying to ask about how one solves ordinary differential equations?

Comment: Thank you for the reply @whuber. I have changed the terminology in the hope that my question is now clearer. I am essentially talking about function composition as mentioned in the title. I am trying to understand the difference between the two specific versions of $h(x)$ and why one was chosen over the other (**second question**) which I believe has something to do with using the differential of $f(x)$ to arrive at the general $h(x)$, and I am trying to understand why (**first question**). You mention utility/interpretability, and I would like to understand the reason in my specific case.

Comment: Short answer: $k=g(x)$ is the analog of reading the speedometer in your car.  The simple model supposes a constant speed; the generalization supposes you have observed the speeds $g$ over time $x$ and determines the location (= distance traveled) at time $x.$  When you're in any situation analogous to analyzing distances traveled in terms of the record of speeds over time, this is the most natural, straightforward approach.

Comment: Thanks, @whuber. I agree that this is an intuitive way of looking at this and understand the principle, having read the paper I cite. In this case $k$ over $x$ is actually not observed. $g(x)$ is assumed *a priori*. My questions relate to your last statement. Why is this “the most natural, straightforward approach”? Would you mind providing a fully worked answer?

Comment: Whether $k$ is observed or not, it has a direct, intuitive meaning about what is happening at time $x,$ whereas the solution function (given by integral) does not have such a simple interpretation.  To use fancier language: the entire idea of the differential calculus, which Newton invented in order to create and analyze models like this, is to analyze complex phenomena into locally linear relationships -- and linear relationships are fundamentally simple to describe and interpret.

Comment: Thank you for providing more detail @whuber. I am still not sure I understand. The integral of $g(x)$ still has an exponential term in it in the specific example, so does not look linear to me. How is it “simple[r] to describe and interpret” when compared with $g(x)$?

Comment: We're talking about the fundamentals of Calculus here, so it will be more productive to refer to a Calculus textbook.